# Получение данных времени из exсel с помощью openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, datetime, openpyxl

Я пытаюсь отпарсить большую Excel таблицу, в которой хранятся данные затраченного времени, в виде (часы:минуты:секунды). Я получаю эта данные с помощью openpyxl:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx"))
sheet = wb.active
cell = sheet['A1'].value
print(cell)
>>> 1900-01-13 13:50:00
```

В ячейке А1 записано 325:50:00, при выводе этих значений, получаю значения типа datetime (1900-01-13 13:50:00). Пробовал изменять формат ячейки напрямую в файлу, не помогло. Не пойму, как можно конвертировано эти данные в минуты, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: *В ячейке А1 записано 325:50:00* - это значение (тип данных текст) или отображение (тип данных время)?

Comment: Тип данных "Время", если поменять на "Текстовый" получаю значение - 13,57638889

Comment: А что выдаёт `type(cell)` ?

Comment: @0andriy, вывод type - <class 'datetime.datetime'>

Comment: `delta = cell - datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 31); print (delta.days * 1440 + delta.seconds / 60)` в вашем примере получается `19550`.

Comment: *Тип данных "Время", если поменять на "Текстовый" получаю значение - 13,57638889* На число надо менять, а не на текст. 5 (или 6) знаков после десятичной точки. Должно получиться 13,57639 как число. А конвертировать обратно... умножь на 24 - сам поймёшь.